# Angular rule to decide when there is name conflict

Tags: angularjs, module

All:

I am pretty new to Angular, I wonder when I include multiple modules, if there are same name controller/service etc, how does angular decide which one to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one limitation of Angular's module system. The order of operation when resolving dependencies is effectively:

1. **Primary Module**
2. **Last Dependent Module Registered**

Imagine the following setup:

```
angular.module('alpha', [])
  .service('fooService', fooService);

angular.module('beta', [])
  .service('fooService', someOtherFooService);

angular.module('my-app', ['alpha', 'beta']);
```

In this case, `someOtherFooService` will always be the dependency injected when requesting it within your application.

Now if we modify the above example to this:

```
angular.module('alpha', [])
  .service('fooService', fooService);

angular.module('my-app', ['alpha'])
  .service('fooService', myFooService);
```

Then `myFooService` will always be the one injected because it is the primary module.

**You can see a more in-depth example of how this plays out in the sample below.**

```js
(function() {

  function serviceFactory(msg) {
    return function() {
      this.sayHello = function() {
        return msg;
      };
    }
  }

  function rollupService(alphaService, betaService, gammaService, deltaService) {

    this.rollup = function() {
      return [
        alphaService.sayHello(),
        betaService.sayHello(),
        gammaService.sayHello(),
        deltaService.sayHello(),
      ].join(" | ");
    };
  }

  angular.module('alpha', [])
    .service('alphaService', serviceFactory("alpha module"))
    .service('betaService', serviceFactory("alpha module"))
    .service('gammaService', serviceFactory("alpha module"))
    .service('deltaService', serviceFactory("alpha module"))
    .service('rollupService', rollupService)
    .run(function(rollupService, $rootScope){
      $rootScope.rollup = rollupService.rollup();
    });

  angular.module('beta', [])
    .service('betaService', serviceFactory("beta module"))
    .service('gammaService', serviceFactory("beta module"))
    .service('deltaService', serviceFactory("beta module"))

  angular.module('gamma', [])
    .service('gammaService', serviceFactory("gamma module"))
    .service('deltaService', serviceFactory("gamma module"))

  angular.module('my-app', ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'])
    .service('deltaService', serviceFactory("my-app module"))
    .controller('myCtrl', function(alphaService, betaService, gammaService, deltaService) {
      this.alphaService = alphaService;
      this.betaService = betaService;
      this.gammaService = gammaService;
      this.deltaService = deltaService;
    });

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
  <h3><code>alphaService.sayHello() = </code>{{ctrl.alphaService.sayHello()}}</h3>
  <h3><code>betaService.sayHello() = </code>{{ctrl.betaService.sayHello()}}</h3>
  <h3><code>gammaService.sayHello() = </code>{{ctrl.gammaService.sayHello()}}</h3>
  <h3><code>deltaService.sayHello() = </code>{{ctrl.deltaService.sayHello()}}</h3>
  <hr />
  <p>Alpha modules dependencies are controller by the application, not how it defined
  it's own dependencies. So watch out cause this could break things.</p>
  <p>This code is run from alpha module's <code>.run</code> block.</p>
  <h3>{{rollup}}</h3>
</div>
```